# Understanding why x ∈ ∩∅ is true for every value of x

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

In [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995), the author mentions:

> ... if F = ∅, then the statement x ∈ ∩F will be true no matter what x is.

If I analyse the logical structure of `x ∈ ∩∅`:

```
x ∈ ∩∅
x ∈ {y | ∀A(A ∈ ∅ → y ∈ A)}
∀A(A ∈ ∅ → x ∈ A)
∀A(F → x ∈ A) Because ∅ has no members
∀A(T ∨ x ∈ A) Conditional law
∀A(x ∈ A)     Tautology law
```

My conclusion supports what the author says, however this doesn't makes sense to me.

`∩F` is supposed to represent the intersection of all the elements of `F`, but if `F` is `∅`, then as far as I understand `F` will not have any element, leading `∩F` to some undefined state as far as I can think of.

How can then `x ∈ ∩∅` be true for every value of `x`?

Comment: You can't find an element of $\emptyset$ that $x$ fails to be a member of. This is just one of those vacuous truths you get used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this would help a bit.

$\bigcap\varnothing$ should be the identity element of intersection operation. Now, think of the case, when all sets involved are subsets of some universe set $U$. In this case, the set $U$ clearly is the identity element for intersection (since if $A \subset U$ then $A \cap U = A$).

So, in a general case, $\bigcap\varnothing$ should be equal to the set of all sets (which does not exist in ZF, by the way).

Comment: When you say "neutral element of intersection operation", do you mean the identity element of intersection operation?

Comment: @jviotti yes, I mean exactly that. Edited the answer.

Comment: @lisyarus: could we say that $\bigcap\varnothing$ is equal to the **class** of all sets (which is not the same as the set of all sets [which does not exist by ZF as you say])?

Comment: @Moritz in case we are talking about intersection of **classes**, yes (note that set intersection is the restriction of the former on sets).